# Old Xen Installation Unable to be Formatted

Tags: ubuntu, partition, swap, xen, gparted

I recently tried to format a disk that had an old Ubuntu 14.04 partition and a Xen Swap Disk partition. I am currently running the Ubuntu Live CD and trying to access my partitions on the drive for formatting and re-installation.

When I open the disk in `Disks` it says there is a full 256GB disk available to be accessed, but when I try to format, I get the message `Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, 0)`.

When I try to access the disk in `Gparted` it says there is 238GB of space, that can be formatted, but i am not able to install ubuntu on that partition when i run the installer. The disk seems to be 16GB smaller than the actual size of the disk, and the old swap disk happened to be 16GB.

I am assuming there is some type of faulty or current swap partition still located on the disk that I cannot access.

I ran the `lvs` command in terminal and nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

This was a combined misconception.

It originates from me confusing GB in `fdisk`, and GiB in `gparted`.
The 256GB disk's representation in GiB is roughly equivalent to the `ubuntu--vg-boot` partition size (~238GB). I assumed that there was some type of hidden partition disk error because of the discrepancy in the capacities, but it was really just me misreading the unit of data.